# How to return parts of a string?

Tags: excel, vba, string

I have these cells:

***Strings in cells***
[image]

I would like to return specific parts of these strings - the "...bar" and "also csatlakozas" or "hatso csatlakozas" - to other cells.

Comment: Please include your current attempt. A visualization of your desired end result would also be prefered. See [ask] a question with an [mcve] and try to edit your question accordingly. Welcome to SO =)... A FYI, looks like a simple formula will do. How set are you on VBA?

Comment: Use `Text-To-Column` method.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code, this should get you started:

```
Sub ExtractMatchingCells()
    'Define in which column data is located
    col = 1
    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, col).End(xlUp).Rows
    
    For i = 1 To lastRow
        ' Extract cell value to cell to the right
        If InStr(0, Cells(i, col), "bar (also csatlakozas)") > 0 Or InStr(0, Cells(i, col), "bar (hatso csatlakozas)") Then
            Cells(i, col + 1) = Cells(i, col)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```